# mapping latitude-longitude to pixel space, in image produced with panoramic equirectangular camera

Tags: camera, panoramic

I am working with a 360 virtual camera in Blender, with latitude angles ranging from -90 to 90 deg and longitude angles ranging from -180 to 180 deg. The rendered images are obtained through equirectangular projection (that is, linear mapping from latitude-longitude to pixel space). Suppose a certain output image has a size of nrows x ncolumns, with longitude increasing from left to right, and latitude increasing from bottom to top.

I was wondering which of the following options for mapping pixels to latitude-longitude is more aligned with how the rendering engine works:

- Would the *centre* of any pixel in the leftmost column of the rendered image correspond to the -180 deg direction?
- Or would the left *edge* of any pixel in the leftmost column correspond to the -180 deg direction?

I think the question can be rephrased as: is a pixel defined as a unique direction or as a small solid angle?

---

**Some more details:**

My understanding initially was that the first mapping is more appropriate. I assumed that for assessing depth or object ID of one pixel, Blender casts a few rays from the camera origin through that pixel, and an average value is taken. I'd expect that in that case, the first and last column of an image (corresponding to -180 and 180 longitude) would be always almost identical. However, this is not the case across my animation. For example when I added object ID images across many frames of my animation, the first and last columns are no longer similar. Shouldn't they be the same always if they represent the -180 and 180 deg directions? If they are not the same, is it possible that the +180 and -180 directions correspond to the edges of the pixels at the leftmost and rightmost columns of the image, rather than the centres? Or is it probably due to an artifact?

I realise the difference is small but I want to make sure I am doing the mapping from latitude-longitude to pixel space correctly, or as aligned as possible with the way the rendering engine works.

Thanks!

Comment: -180 corresponds to the *edge*.  Otherwise, there would be overlap-- would you sample from the right column or the left column at -180.1 degrees?

Comment: @Nathan so then I understand a pixel corresponds to data from a small solid angle, rather than from a unique direction? That is, the data in the pixel in the bottom left corner comes from rays with longitude angles ranging from -180 to -180+(360/ncolumns) and latitude angles ranging from -90 to -90+(180/nrows). Is that correct? That would be in line with the code [here] I think (https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/118664e4631a29c9a4f1f8e06be124c8ea3a006a/intern/cycles/kernel/kernel_projection.h#L66). I think I am confused bcause I don't understand well how the sampling within a pixel works

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  At 180 degrees longitude, you're sampling exactly between the right and left edges from an X-tiled, Y-mirrored version of the image.  Pixels are rarely sampled as single indivisible chunks (but you can force that with closest sampling.)  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_filtering for more information about how textures are generally sampled.

Comment: this was very helpful, thank you!